# How to use MongoDB aggregate to get the first of each group, including nulls?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB `people` collection I need to filter people with the same 'alias' property value, keeping the first one of them, and also keeping all people with a null 'alias'.

Some sample people data:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Alice",    "alias" : null },
{ "_id" : "2", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Bob",      "alias" : "afa776bea788cf4c" },
{ "_id" : "3", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Bobby",    "alias" : "afa776bea788cf4c" },
{ "_id" : "4", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Cristina", "alias" : null },
{ "_id" : "5", "flag" : false, "name" : "Diego",    "alias" : null },
{ "_id" : "6", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Zoe",      "alias" : "2211293acc82329a" },
```

This is the result I expect:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "Alice",    "alias" : null },
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Bob",      "alias" : "afa776bea788cf4c" },
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "Cristina", "alias" : null },
{ "_id" : "6", "name" : "Zoe",      "alias" : "2211293acc82329a" },
```

I've come with this initial query:

```
db.people.aggregate({ $group: { _id: '$alias', alias: { $first: '$alias' } } })
```

The first problem I face is that this returns only `_id` and `alias` fields, but I need all of them...

**UPDATE**:
I have changed a bit sample data to better reflect my use case, since @user3100115 answer solves the issue for old sample data, but not for real data.

What I did change:

- add one more document ("Cristina") with a null alias (my documents all have "alias" field), since I need **all** documents with a null alias value to be returned, and not just the first one.
- add one more boolean property ("flag"), which I need to be able to match, too... I.e.: using `find()` I'd do: `db-people.find({flag:true})`, but I don't understand how to filter with more fields with `aggregate()`...

*Please tell me if you think I should better place a new question...*

Comment: What do you want to do if many document don't have alias?

Comment: Just so you know, you can have the names become an array of all the names for that alias, ie ['Alice'] ['Bob', 'Bobby'] ['Zoe'], so taht you can access the first one by name[0]. If you are interested in that, modify your question accordingly ( https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/push/ )

Comment: @user3100115: return all of them

Comment: @Daniel F: Thanks! I didn't know it... Probably I will use that...

Comment: @MarcoS You're welcome. In the accepted answer, in the first code block, fourth line use `'name':  { '$push': '$name'},`. Then there's also the `$unwind` stage, in case you want to "ungroup" that 'name' array for individual access in later stages.

Comment: Oh I can see that you edited your question to create a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). That being said you can have many document with the same `_id` value as you posted.

Comment: @ user3100115: Sorry, didn't want to break any etiquette... :-) Will post a new question, if I'll need to change something else... However, the issue was not with duplicated _id's (just my mistake, corrected question), but about getting **all** documents with null `alias`, *and* the possibility to add a condition in filter (added `flag` property in sample data).

Comment: @MarcoS edited my answer. But again please next time make sure you post the right data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to return the the `_id` value in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage.

```js
db.people.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': { 'flag': true } }, 
    { '$project': {
        'name': 1,          
        'alias': { 
            '$cond': [
                { '$eq': [ '$alias', null ] }, 
                '$_id', 
                '$alias' 
            ]
        }
    }},
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$alias',         
        'name':  { '$first': '$name' },          
        'id': { '$first': '$_id' }       
    }}, 
    { '$project': {
        'alias': {
            '$cond': [ 
                { '$eq': [ '$id', '$_id' ] }, 
                null, 
               '$_id' 
            ]
        }, 
        'name': 1,
        '_id': '$id'
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : "6", "name" : "Zoe", "alias" : "2211293acc82329a" }
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "Cristina", "alias" : null }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Bob", "alias" : "afa776bea788cf4c" }
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "Alice", "alias" : null }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need all your fields you can use [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) to references the root document. It will keep all fields of the document in a one field.

```
Person.aggregate([
    {
        $project:
        {
            alias: {$ifNull: ['$alias', "$_id"] },
            name: 1,
            document: "$$ROOT"
        }
    },
    { $group: { _id: "$alias", name: {$first: "$name"}, document: {$first: "$document"}}},
    {
        $project: { _id:0, document: 1}
    }
], function (err, documents) {
    var result = documents.map(function(doc){
        return doc.document;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need all the fields including the original `_id` you need to specify them all in the grouping and then additionally do a projection:

```
db.entries.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: '$alias', alias: { $first: '$alias' }, name: {$first: '$name'}, id: {$first: '$_id'} } }, {$project: {_id: '$id', name: '$name', alias: '$alias'}}])
```