# MongoDb: How to aggregate, group and sort on date field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB people collection I need to filter people with the same 'alias' property value, keeping the first one of them, and also keeping all people with a null 'alias'.

Data is like this:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Alice",    "alias" : null, "dateOfBirth": new ISODate('1995-12-27T00:00:00.000Z') },
{ "_id" : "2", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Bob",      "alias" : "4c", "dateOfBirth": new ISODate('1996-12-27T00:00:00.000Z') },
{ "_id" : "3", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Bobby",    "alias" : "4c", "dateOfBirth": new ISODate('1997-12-27T00:00:00.000Z') },
{ "_id" : "4", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Cristina", "alias" : null, "dateOfBirth": new ISODate('1998-12-27T00:00:00.000Z') },
{ "_id" : "5", "flag" : false, "name" : "Diego",    "alias" : null, "dateOfBirth": new ISODate('1999-12-27T00:00:00.000Z') },
{ "_id" : "6", "flag" : true,  "name" : "Zoe",      "alias" : "22", "dateOfBirth": new ISODate('2000-12-27T00:00:00.000Z') }
```

This is my query:

```js
db.people.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': { 'flag': true } }, 
    { '$project': {
        'name': 1,          
        'alias': { 
            '$cond': [
                { '$eq': [ '$alias', null ] }, 
                '$_id', 
                '$alias' 
            ]
        }
    }},
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$alias',         
        'name':  { '$first': '$name' },          
        'id': { '$first': '$_id' }       
    }}, 
    { '$project': {
        'alias': {
            '$cond': [ 
                { '$eq': [ '$id', '$_id' ] }, 
                null, 
               '$_id' 
            ]
        }, 
        'name': 1,
        '_id': '$id'
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : "6", "name" : "Zoe",      "alias" : "22" }
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "Cristina", "alias" : null }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Bob",      "alias" : "4c" }
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "Alice",    "alias" : null }
```

So far so good.

**UPDATE:** Up to this point the qestion is similar to [suggested duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375163). Now comes the different part:

I need to sort it according to "dateOfBirth" field.
Very confident, I changed the query to:

```js
db.people.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': { 'flag': true } }, 
    { '$project': {
        'name': 1,          
        'dateOfBirth': 1,
        'alias': { 
            '$cond': [
                { '$eq': [ '$alias', null ] }, 
                '$_id', 
                '$alias' 
            ]
        }
    }},
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$alias',         
        'name':  { '$first': '$name' },          
        'dateOfBirth': { '$first': '$dateOfBirth' },
        'id': { '$first': '$_id' }       
    }}, 
    { '$project': {
        'alias': {
            '$cond': [ 
                { '$eq': [ '$id', '$_id' ] }, 
                null, 
               '$_id' 
            ]
        }, 
        'name': 1,
        '_id': '$id',
        'dateOfBirth': 1,
    }},
    { '$sort': { 'dateOfBirth': 1 }}
])
```

But this gives:

```js
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "Alice",    "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("1995-12-27T00:00:00Z"), "alias" : null }
{ "_id" : "6", "name" : "Zoe",      "dateOfBirth" : null, "alias" : "22" }
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "Cristina", "dateOfBirth" : null, "alias" : null }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Bob",      "dateOfBirth" : null, "alias" : "4c" }
```

Which is wrong, of course: `dateOfBirth` field does not pass the `$group` stage...

Any clue on how to let it pass through?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use MongoDB aggregate to get the first of each group, including nulls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375163/how-to-use-mongodb-aggregate-to-get-the-first-of-each-group-including-nulls)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually that works just fine for me, and I suspect you have a typo in the real code you are running ( not that listing ) that was missing the inclusion of "dateOfBirth" somewhere ( or possibly mispelled ).

But if there is a lesson to be learned here, it should be to not seperate [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages as it's not only inefficient to introduce another pipeline stage ( this means an extra pass through data ) but it a common cause for confusion when specifying data to include in the pipeline.

So rather do:

```js
db.people.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "flag": true } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$ifNull": [ "$alias", "$_id" ]
        },
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "dateOfBirth": { "$first": "$dateOfBirth" },
        "id": { "$first": "$_id" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "name": 1,
        "dateOfBirth": 1,
        "alias": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$id" ] },
                null,
                "$_id"
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "dateOfBirth": 1 } }
])
```

Which also makes use of [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) as a natural test rather than working with `$cond` where you do not need to.

And of course the desired result is returned:

```js
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "Alice", "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("1995-12-27T00:00:00Z"), "alias" : null }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Bob", "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("1996-12-27T00:00:00Z"), "alias" : "4c" }
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "Cristina", "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("1998-12-27T00:00:00Z"), "alias" : null }
{ "_id" : "6", "name" : "Zoe", "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("2000-12-27T00:00:00Z"), "alias" : "22" }
```

If you wanted "first by date of birth", then move the sort before the `$group` stage and the `$first` operator will do all the work there.

Comment: You're right on both sides: my question did contain a working solution alrteady, but I badly wrote dateOfBirth field name when inserting in my test collection... :-( And, the advise you give is very interesting, since it simplifies and speeds up the query: with sample data it is not simple to compare results, but with the query "before", I sometimes get an exec time of 1 ms, and with the query "after" I *always* get 0 ms...

Comment: Profiling a bit my old query with yours, even if in a quite 'naive' way (<Reload> in browser...), results have a big variance, but minimum timings are 80 ms for old query, and 60 ms for new one (YMMV, of course).