# Retrieving a relationship field in mongodb aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, strapi

I am using mongodb aggregation with a collection named **files**
that has a relationship with another collection named **file_upload**.

```
files = {
 type: String,
 media:  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'file_upload', required: true },
}

file_upoad = {
 name: String,
}
```

This is the query

```
const data = await strapi.query('files').model.aggregate([
      {
          $lookup: {
              from: "analytics",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "file_id",
              as: "hits",
          }
      },
      { $unwind: '$hits' },
      { $group: { _id: "$_id", hitsCount: { $sum: 1 } } },
      { $sort: { hitsCount: -1 } },
      { $limit: 1 },
  ])
```

my goal is to retrieve the **media** as part of the result since it is a relationship field, at the moment I get this

```
[
{
    "_id": "61fd74367b6ee77b89bae34d",
    "hitsCount": 12
},
{
    "_id": "61fd74367b6ee77b89sddfee",
    "hitsCount": 8
}
]
```

expected result

```
[
 {
    "_id": "61fd74367b6ee77b89bae34d",
    "hitsCount": 12,
    "media": {
           name:"name1"
    }
 },
{
    "_id": "61fd74367b6ee77b89sddfee",
    "hitsCount": 8,
     "media": {
          name:"name2"
     }
}
]
```

Comment: Perhaps with $first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375163/how-to-use-mongodb-aggregate-to-get-the-first-of-each-group-including-nulls